# Python code execution is not stopping of newton rapson method

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
import math
def f(x):
  return (3**x-math.cos(x)-1)
```

it return 3x-cosx-1

```
def f1(x):
  return (3+math.sin(x))
```

it return integrated result

```
def Newton_Raphson_Method(x0,e):
  iter=1
  condition=True
  while condition:
    if f1(x0)==0.0:
      print("Error")
      break
  x1=(x0-f(x0))/f1(x0)
  print("Interation no %d, root is %f" %(iter,x1))
  x0=x1
  condition=abs(f(x1))>e
  iter=iter+1
  print("Final answer %f"%(x1))
```

But the function running and executing
x0=float(input("Enter the Guess "))
e=float(input("Enter the tolerable error "))
Newton_Raphson_Method(x0,e)

after giving input in newton raphson method  it running simulantously and didn't stop.it run doesn't stop

Comment: Should you be checking if `f(x) == 0.0` or if it's within tolerable limits (epsilon) since Newton-raphson produces an approximate solution?

Comment: `2 <= (3 + sinx)  <= 4` so your f1(x) will never become 0.0 so while(1) run infinitely

Comment: How can i slove it?

Comment: write question properly, what do you want, and 3**x is 3^x (x  power of 3) so be careful, you have written wrong code, also fix indentation(code structuring) , as python is indentation sensitive.